# Can we create subtypes for errors in Go?

Tags: go, types, error-handling, subtype, type-switch

I want to create hierarchical errors in Go. Can we achieve this in Go ?
For an example, I have following two errors.

```golang
type Error1 struct {
    reason string
    cause error
}

func (error1 Error1) Error() string {
    if error1.cause == nil || error1.cause.Error() == "" {
        return fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR]: %s\n", error1.reason)
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR]: %s\nCaused By: %s\n", error1.reason, error1.cause)
    }
}

type Error2 struct {
    reason string
    cause error
}

func (error2 Error2) Error() string {
    if error2.cause == nil || error2.cause.Error() == "" {
        return fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR]: %s\n", error2.reason)
    } else {
        return fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR]: %s\nCause: %s", error2.reason, error2.cause)
    }
}
```

I want to have an error type `CommonError` which consists of two sub-types, `Error1` and `Error1`, so that I can do the following.

```
func printType(param error) {
    switch t := param.(type) {
    case CommonError:
        fmt.Println("Error1 or Error 2 found")
    default:
        fmt.Println(t, " belongs to an unidentified type")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

**Edit:**

In the type switch we can use multiple errors like this:
`case Error1, Error2:` but When I have a larger number of errors, or when I need some abstraction for the errors inside a module, this approach won't be the best one.

Comment: You may use `case Error1, Error2:`, isn't that enough?

Comment: The issue is when I have a large number of errors, it's quite hard to put all the errors like this. Another problem is that if I want to use this in another module, I just want an abstraction for the errors I have.

Comment: No need to roll your own: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/xerrors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may list multiple types in a `case`, so this will do what you want:

```
switch t := param.(type) {
case Error1, Error2:
    fmt.Println("Error1 or Error 2 found")
default:
    fmt.Println(t, " belongs to an unidentified type")
}
```

Testing it:

```
printType(Error1{})
printType(Error2{})
printType(errors.New("other"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ipfn2DpuPzL)):

```
Error1 or Error 2 found
Error1 or Error 2 found
other  belongs to an unidentified type
```

If you want to "group" the errors, another solution is to create a "marker" interface:

```
type CommonError interface {
    CommonError()
}
```

Which `Error1` and `Error2` must implement:

```
func (Error1) CommonError() {}

func (Error2) CommonError() {}
```

And then you can do:

```
switch t := param.(type) {
case CommonError:
    fmt.Println("Error1 or Error 2 found")
default:
    fmt.Println(t, " belongs to an unidentified type")
}
```

Testing it with the same, output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EEGR2kNUvaX).

If you want to restrict `CommonError`s to be "true" errors, also embed the `error` interface:

```
type CommonError interface {
    error
    CommonError()
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but can we achieve different levels of errors by this (the 2nd) approach ?

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge You can have multiple "marker" interfaces, e.g. `CommonError1`, `CommonError2` etc. You can also "combine" these, e.g. `CommonError2` may embed `CommonError1`, so if an error is `CommonError2`, that also must be `CommonError1` too.

Comment: I asked a different question on this, if you can please have a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581400/how-to-create-multi-level-error-subtypes-in-go?noredirect=1#comment99740630_56581400

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the simplest way to achieve what you want is through error *wrapping:*

```
var (
    CommonError  = errors.New("common error")
    SpecificError = fmt.Errorf("%w: specific message", CommonError)
    AnotherError = fmt.Errorf("%w: another message", CommonError)
)
```

You may check for the type of error with

```
if errors.Is(err, CommonError) {
    // will execute on SpecificError or AnotherError
} else {
    // will execute for all other types of errors
}
```