# How to create multi-level Error subtypes in Go

Tags: go, types, error-handling, subtyping, type-switch

I was trying to create sub-types of errors in GO. [I've asked a question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580030/can-we-create-subtypes-for-errors-in-go) regarding the matter.

Now I'am facing an issue with the multiple types. Following code shows the error type definitions:

```golang
/* Interfaces */
type UniversalError interface {
    CommonError1
}

type CommonError1 interface {
    error
    CommonError1()
}

/* Structs */
type Error1 struct {
    reason string
}

type Error2 struct {
    reason string
}

type Error3 struct {
    reason string
}

/* Interface function implementations */
func (error1 Error1) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(error1.reason)
}

func (error2 Error2) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(error2.reason)
}

func (error3 Error3) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(error3.reason)
}

func (Error1) CommonError1() {}
func (Error2) CommonError1() {}
func (Error3) UniversalError() {}
```

When I try to run the following code:

```golang
func main() {
    var err1 = Error1{reason: "Error reason 1"}
    var err2 = Error2{reason: "Error reason 2"}
    var err3 = Error3{reason: "Error reason 3"}

    fmt.Println("\n**** Types *****")
    printType(err1)
    printType(err2)
    printType(err3)
}

func printType(param error) {
    switch param.(type) {
    case UniversalError:
        switch param.(type) {
        case CommonError1:
            switch param.(type) {
            case Error1:
                fmt.Println("Error1 found")
            case Error2:
                fmt.Println("Error2 found")
            default:
                fmt.Println("CommonError1 found, but Does not belong to Error1 or Error2")
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println("Error3 Found")
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println("Error belongs to an unidentified type")
    }
}
```

The `printType()` function prints the following:

```sh
**** Types *****
Error1 found
Error2 found
CommonError1 found, but Does not belong to Error1 or Error2
```

I need the type of `Error3` to be identified as an `UniversalError`, but not as a `CommonError1`. How can I achieve this ? Is there anything wrong in my approach ?

Comment: You can't. There are no "subtypes", no parents/children, no class hierarchy, no inheritance, and no polymorphism beyond interfaces in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `UniversalError()` method, but you did not add that to the interface "definition", so do that:

```
type UniversalError interface {
    CommonError1
    UniversalError()
}
```

And you want `Error3` to be a `UniversalError`. For `Error3` to be a `UniversalError`, it must implement all its methods: `UniversalError()` and `CommonError1()`. So you have to add both those methods:

```
func (Error3) CommonError1()   {}
func (Error3) UniversalError() {}
```

With these changes, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NTpBp_C6WxV)):

```
**** Types *****
Error belongs to an unidentified type
Error belongs to an unidentified type
CommonError1 found, but Does not belong to Error1 or Error2
```

**Tip:** If you want compile-time guarantee that some concrete type implements some interface, use a blank variable declaration like this:

```
var _ UniversalError = Error3{}
```

The above declaration assigns a value of `Error3` to a variable of type `UniversalError`. Should `Error3` not satisfy `UniversalError`, you get a compile-time error. The above declaration will not introduce a new variable as the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) was used, this is just a compile-time check.

If you would remove the `Error3.CommonError1()` method:

```
//func (Error3) CommonError1()   {}
func (Error3) UniversalError() {}
```

Then you would get a compile-time error right away:

```
./prog.go:49:5: cannot use Error3 literal (type Error3) as type UniversalError in assignment:
    Error3 does not implement UniversalError (missing CommonError1 method)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this case, why don't `Error1` and `Error2` aren't recognized as `UniversalError` ?
Here I need 2 super types.
1. Consists of `Error1` and `Error2` -> the `CommonError1`
2. Consists of `CommonError1` and `Error3` -> Universal Error.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge `UniversalError` embeds `CustomError1`, not the other way round. If you want opposite relation, embedding should reflect that. Looks you want all your errors to be "universal", so `CustomError1` and `CustomError2` should embed `UniversalError`. Implemented methods must be according to that.

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood it. Thank you.